# How to convert HTML to PDF with Bookmark

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to save a customized html file as a pdf.. normally I would press ctrl-P at my browser (chrome) and print as pdf..

[image: saving html as pdf]

But when I open the pdf file, there is no bookmark tab on the left side of the pdf reader (adobe)..

[image: pdf without bookmark]

What I want is to save an html file as a pdf and the bookmark should appear in the left side of the pdf reader:

[image]

I created the html file.. I added links to some parts of it using `id` and hyperlink:

```
<a href="#part1">part1</a>
...some codes here...
<div id="part1">
```

and it works, but I don't know how to create a bookmark in pdf from an html... normally ms word or libre office can convert their documents to pdf with a bookmark..

But how can I made a pdf with a bookmark using HTML?

Comment: Any luck? The same problem has plagued me for a year and I never found a solution. Possibly everyone prints to epub now and forgot to tell us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I ran into this problem and *really* wanted there to be a solution here that worked.  When there wasn't, I figured I should add what I found so that hopefully the *next* developer can benefit from it.

**First up: HTML conversion to PDF isn't really *up* to the HTML itself** - it's up to whatever the conversion engine decides to do with your HTML.  So for instance, if your approach is: Open it in IE/Chrome/Firefox/whatever > File > Print > Microsoft Print to PDF - well, your conversion engine is 'Microsoft Print to PDF'.  Doesn't matter what *browser* you were using at that point - all its doing is creating a print stream to send to a printer.  So if Microsoft Print to PDF isn't going to make bookmarks for you (which it doesn't) then it doesn't matter *which* web browser you use to open the PDF.

**And this is the critical problem with any Ctrl-P / Print avenues.  The web browser is ultimately creating a *print stream*, which the conversion library simply streams into a PDF.**  And all the web browsers I looked at do *not* have native support built in to convert to PDF (why would they?  99% of the use cases are covered with a 'Print to PDF' functionality.)  And the print drivers I tried (Microsoft Print to PDF, Adobe PDF Print) didn't manage to suss out bookmarks from the raw print stream.  Which makes sense.

So, at this point, what you're looking for is a standalone PDF Conversion engine - something that can actively open the HTML file and convert from there, instead of going through a web browser.  *Are* there PDF Conversion engines that do this and add Header-Tag based bookmarks?  Possibly.  The ones we had at our disposal (ABCPdf, Neevia) weren't able to do it, but it's certainly possible there's one out there.

So what now?

There are a few different options I explored.

**Option #1: Separate Files, Combined With Adobe**

Adobe Acrobat (non-viewer version), when *it's* the conversion engine, will automatically add bookmarks for each *file* it converts.  So you can submit the HTML contents, not as a single HTML file, but as HTML files for each section you want a bookmark over.

The good news is that if a section has a hyperlink that points to another document its merging, it's smart enough to have that hyperlink point to the spot within the internal PDF its creating (it's not an external hyperlink like I expected it would be).  There are two bits of bad news, though:

- Each section has to be the start of a PDF page.  If your section is
  two inches tall, the rest of the page will be blank, and the next
  section will start on the following page.
- The bookmarks aren't clean.  When I did it, each file had 3
  bookmarks.  Which is pretty darned ugly and off-putting.

**Option #2: Separate Files, Combined With Another Library**

The first 'downside' of Option #1 might not be a problem.  But the second is pretty ugly.  And other libraries definitely *can* create the bookmarks without creating 3-per-file.  The main obstacle here is: the library has to be smart enough to resolve those 'external' hyperlinks to within the PDF that's created.  One thing that often hurts is that those conversion libraries often want to convert each separate file to a PDF internally first and then merge the PDFs together... but that means that it won't handle the cross-file hyperlinks correctly.  I wasn't able to find a way to make this work with our existing PDF conversion libraries.

**Option #3: Different Origination Method**

Instead of having a 'Help.html', which is then converted to PDF somehow, start with a format *other* than HTML.  And the easiest source to get into PDF+Bookmarks is MSWord+Headers.  Generally, for each PDF help file you want, you can have a master .DOCX sitting somewhere behind the scenes.  We've used this approach before, and while it's not the most elegant, it at least works pretty well.

**Option #4: Programmatic with Library**

This might not be applicable for the OP's use case... but if you're *generating* the help, there's nothing to say you can't use the PDF Conversion library *programatically* to add whatever bookmarks you want.  Pretty much every PDF engine I've seen allows API access to bookmarks, so if this avenue is open to you, it's almost certainly the cleanest solution-wise.

**Option #5: PDF Conversion Scouring**

Like I mentioned, it's possible there's a PDF conversion engine out there that has a good HTML parsing engine and can handle bookmarks from various HTML tags (like H1, H2, etc.)  However, it's probably going to take a bit to find it, because it's *so much easier* for a potential engine-writer to allow the file to be rendered with a native viewer.  Think about it.  If you were writing a PDF Conversion Service, which would you rather do:

- Develop routines that can *accurately* render an HTML document fed
  into it - aka, basically write your own web browser from scratch.
- Have IE/Chrome/Whatever render it and simply take their print output
  to convert to PDF.

... that second option is so ridiculously easier than the first, that it's no surprise most PDF Conversion engines don't have their own internal HTML parser (or for that matter, Word parser, Excel parser, etc.)

Comment: (Nice overview.) PrinceXML is pretty good. And it does [bookmarks](https://www.princexml.com/doc/5.1/pdf-bookmarks/). It's free to try, with a watermark.

Comment: Great options! well this question is 4 years old now, and as you say, there is currently no direct option (as I understand) to convert html to pdf with bookmarks. What I originally wanted to know before is to find if there are some html tags/elements/attributes that can be translated as bookmarks on pdf.

Answer well explained.

Comment: A slight correction in that ABCpdf (since version 11) does support a method for doing this. First you would need to convert the HTML to PDF (as specified here: https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2F6-abcpdf.objects%2Fbookmark%2Fdefault.htm). You should then be able extract those links and create bookmarks for them. ABCpdf allows such low-level access. ABCpdf support will be able to assist you in this.

Comment: @PeterG - isn't that 'Option 4' - using a programmatic approach with the library?  I mean, yeah, it has an API point to explicitly add a bookmark... but nothing out of the box to take an HTML and have it automatically add bookmarks based on any of the HTML tags.

Comment: @Kevin I just wanted to correct your comment in the 4th paragraph that "... ABCPdf ... [wasn't] able to do it, but it's certainly possible there's one out there." You could develop an application to do it using ABCpdf. We are considering adding a facility to facilitate this more easily at HTML conversion time if there seems to be a demand.

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarks in html input document are set like this:

```
<a href="#bookmark1">.... </a>
...
...
...
<h1 id="marcador1"> Chapter 1 </h1>
...
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more or add some clear details on how?

Comment: For a specific page by number:

<a href="http://www.domain.com/file.pdf#page=3">Link text</a>
For a named location (destination):

<a href="http://www.domain.com/file.pdf#nameddest=TOC">Link text</a>
To create destinations within a PDF with Acrobat:

Manually navigate through the PDF for the desired location
Go to View > Navigation Tabs > Destinations
Under Options, choose Scan Document
Once this is completed, select New Destination from the Options menu and enter an appropriate name

Comment: It seems that my question is unclear... my question is, HOW can I make bookmarks in pdf through html... not how to link html to pdf bookmarks...

Comment: By linking in the html

Comment: well this is not what I'm looking for.. btw.. thanks for trying to answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use chrome, although it is simple to convert a web page to a PDF file. If you want pdf bookmarks, you can try microsoft word (2010). Just save the web pages to local, and open it with MS word 2010, then save it as pdf. The bookmark is there. see also: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF2.html

Comment: Microsoft Word 2016 works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### App comparison for converting PDF (regarding bookmark & internal hyperlink)

I did some tests for different app, (results may not be accurate due to personal settings / mis-used)

|  | pdf bookmark | internal hyperlink | downloaded as .htm | file format looking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome (print as PDF) | N | Y | N | looks same as the webpage |
| Calibre | Y | N/Y | Y | looks same as the webpage |
| Print Friendly & PDF 2.8.1 (Chrome Extension) | N | Y | N | syntax color is changed |
| WPS docx | N/Y | N | Y | format is changed a lot |
| Foxit PDF | N | N | Y | looks same as the webpage |
| Adobe PDF | N | N | Y | looks same as the webpage |
| MS Word docx |  |  |  |  |
| Adobe PDF (Chrome Extension) |  |  |  |  |

annotation:

- `pdf bookmark` = contains bookmark in PDF file
- `internal hyperlink` =

  - Y = the web hyperlinks inside jumps to the position in the PDF internally
  - N = the web hyperlinks inside opens an external web link in your browser
- `downloaded as .htm` =

  - Y = the webpage is downloaded as .htm then converted to PDF
  - N = the webpage is directly converted in Chrome browser
- `file format looking`

  - (Though I said "looks same as the webpage", its not "exactly" same as the webpage -- you need to config the settings when you convert.

    Also some minor parts / components of the webpage may or may not be contained in the PDF.)

#### Calibre Usage

##### To use Calibre <sub><sup>(As shown, Calibre contains the bookmark. But it doesnt have `internal hyperlink`.)</sup></sub>

1. webpage is downloaded as .htm (along with a folder)
2. drag the `.htm` into Calibre, it becomes a .zip file
3. use `Convert books` to convert .zip to .pdf
4. You may need to set up the bookmark detection mechanism in `Convert books > Table of Contents` if Calibre doesnt detect it.

- Calibre is highly customizable on the conversion
- (wish I know how to solve the issue of "not having `internal hyperlink`" directly inside Calibre, without going through HTTrack)

##### To use Calibre, with HTTrack to add `internal hyperlink`:

1. use HTTrack to download the webpage

   (with depth of level of 1 (--ie: just current webpage), should be enough)

   (you may need to config it so that it captures external files like images / syntax-format files)
2. drag the `index.html` into Calibre ... (proceed same as [2~4] above)

   (you need to enable the option of creating the `index.html`)

#### WPS docx Usage <sub><sup>(not recommend)</sup></sub>

1. webpage is downloaded as .htm (along with a folder)
2. save as .docx
3. output as .pdf (enable the option `convert title style format to bookmark`)
4. (if no `title style format` is detected, that may due to the `title` are actually in the style format of `hyperlink style format`, you need to manually remove all those `hyperlink style format`.)

#### <sub><sup>note</sup></sub>

- testing subject weblink is [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html) ; (testing result PDF  are not posted here)
- Again, I could be wrong -- results may not be accurate due to personal settings / mis-used

  Personally, I believe big companies like Adobe should have such functionality to include bookmarks in PDF. It just I dont know how to do it...